# Vault On GKE - x509: cannot validate certificate for 127.0.0.1 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs

Tags: ssl, google-kubernetes-engine, hashicorp-vault

I've created a certificate for the commonName "vault-lab.company.com" within Certificate Manager in the Istio namespace.

I've then used Reflector to copy that secret across to the Vault namespace, like so:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: vault-lab.company.com-cert
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  secretName: vault-lab.company.com-cert
  commonName: vault-lab.company.com
  dnsNames:
  - vault-lab.company.com
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-prod-istio
    kind: ClusterIssuer
  secretTemplate:
    annotations:
      reflector.v1.k8s.emberstack.com/reflection-allowed: "true"  
      reflector.v1.k8s.emberstack.com/reflection-allowed-namespaces: "vault"  # Control destination namespaces
      reflector.v1.k8s.emberstack.com/reflection-auto-enabled: "true" # Auto create reflection for matching namespaces
      reflector.v1.k8s.emberstack.com/reflection-auto-namespaces: "vault" # Control auto-reflection namespaces
```

The secret is successfully mounted via the volumes and volumeMounts section of the *values.yaml* for Vault:

```
  volumes:
    - name: vault-lab-cert
      secret:
        secretName: vault-lab.company.com-cert
  volumeMounts: 
        mountPath: /etc/tls
        readOnly: true
```

And in reading https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/212, I've set the following as well in the listener configuration:

```
config: |
      ui = false
      listener "tcp" {
        tls_disable = false
        address = "0.0.0.0:8200"
        tls_cert_file = "/etc/tls/tls.crt"
        tls_key_file = "/etc/tls/tls.key"
      }
      api_addr = "https://vault-lab.company.com:8200"
      cluster_addr = "https://vault-lab.company.com:8201"
```

However, I'm still seeing:

```
Get "https://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/seal-status": x509: cannot validate certificate for 127.0.0.1 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs
```

When running:

```
kubectl exec vault-0 -- vault status
```

Interestingly, if I describe the *vault-0* pod via *kubectl*, I see:

```
VAULT_ADDR:                      https://127.0.0.1:8200
VAULT_API_ADDR:                  https://$(POD_IP):8200
```

What could I be missing?
Is there something more I need to do if the certificate is configured via Cert Manager?

There's not a great deal of documentation on how to set this up at all.

Comment: certificate verification tries to put together what you use as the host in your request (in your case `127.0.0.1` with what the certificate is issued for (in your case `vault-lab.company.com`) And if that doesn't fit there is an error. So either use the correct host for the request or add `127.0.0.1` as an IP to the certificate (yeah, you can also create certificates for IP addresses)

Comment: @derpirscher - Adding 127.0.01 to a certificate doesn't seem like the greatest of ideas from a security standpoint. 
The kubectl command that gives the error defaults to sending the request to 127.0.0.1, so I'm not really sure how to go about changing that. It must be something to do with the values.yaml file, right?

Comment: What would be the security problem with having 127.0.0.1 in the certificate? Acutally I don't think you would need any certificates at all for localhost or 127.0.0.1 only, because those requests can -- per definition -- only originiate from and target on the very same machine ...

Comment: My presumption was that it could be a potential issue for Man in the Middle attacks, but after reading the LetsEncrypt article, my presumption was incorrect; you shouldn't add localhost, but 127.0.0.1 is OK for native/web apps. 
I'll try adding that in to the certificate and will see how I get on. Thanks for the pointer :)

Answer (score 1):

When you run `vault status`, the binary runs as a client, unaware of the server configuration, even if it's running on the same machine or container. That means `vault status` can't read the `listener` stanza of your configuration file. It defaults to `https://127.0.0.1:8200` that is missing from your certificate. The solution is not to add this IP address, but to tell Vault CLI where to find the server.

You can confirm that this is the problem with this command (should work, assuming your certificate is OK):

```
kubectl exec vault-0 -- vault status --address https://vault-lab.company.com:8200
```

For the client to pick up the API address automatically, set the [`VAULT_ADDR` environment variable](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/commands#vault_addr) in your container to:

```
VAULT_ADDR=https://vault-lab.company.com:8200
```